# Rails/Ruby ordering / splitting it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iteration

```
<% 
  old_city = ""
  @objects.order("city").each do |obj|
    if old_city != obj.city && old_city != ""
      old_city = obj.city
%>
  --Different city--
<%
    end
%>
  City: <%= obj.city %>
<%
 end
%>

So that output expected is:
Chicago
Chicago
--Different city--
New York
New York
New York
--Different city--
Paris
--Different city--
Rio de Janeiro
```

Maybe there's some cleaver/different way to do that in rails?

I don't think this is the best code for it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options, but [`Enumerable` offers a `group_by` method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by).

`group_by` takes a block to define groupings. After grouping it's a matter of iterating over the resulting map's keys.

```
objs = [
  { :foo => 'baz', :wat => 'kthxbai' },
  { :foo => 'bar', :wat => 'narnar' },
  { :foo => 'plugh', :wat => 'xyzzy' },
  { :foo => 'bar', :wat => 'ohai' },
  { :foo => 'baz', :wat => 'fuuuu' },
  { :foo => 'plugh', :wat => 'jimmies' }
]

grouped = objs.group_by { |o| o[:foo] }
grouped.each do |k, v|
  puts "GROUP: #{k}"
  v.each { |v| puts v }
end
```

If you want to order by keys, you can do that too by sorting the keys and retrieving the resulting map's values while iterating over the sorted keys.

If they're `ActiveRecord`s you  might want to do the work in SQL/`ActiveRecord` proper.

Comment: Ok, that works for my example... but what i've got here is a little more complex... its an ActveRecord that has a has_many relationship that also uses a has_one relationship, i got @foo.bars.include(:fuuu), almost forgot that i've to group by 2 fields :) any hint on how to do that

Comment: @BernardoMendes No problem :) Did you try using an ActiveRecord approach? Moving this kind of work in to the DB layer can often be faster.

Comment: I used group_by, when grouping using sql group by i just get one record per grouped fields... am i doing this right?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in the console:

```
Event.order(:city).group_by(&:city)
```

This will return a hash where the keys will be the individual cities and the values will be arrays of the corresponding event objects. You can then easily iterate over the hash's keys, and in an inner loop, iterate over the corresponding event objects.

Comment: Hey @maprihoda, what is the difference between :city and &:city, what & does in ror? Thank you

Comment: @Bernardo You are ordering by `city`, and grouping by `object[:city]`. `group_by(&:city)` is a shorter form of `group_by { |o| o[:city] }`